# Area of a rectangle under transformation $e^{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $$\Omega=\left\{x+ \iota y:-1 \leq x \leq2,\frac{-\pi}{3}\leq y \leq \frac{\pi}{3}\right\}$$

Now question is what will be the area of this rectangle under transforamtion
$$x+\iota y \to e^{x+ \iota y}$$

Solution i tried -The given Transformation is a rotation so it will only rotate the  given curve ,but i can find the proper solution i.e proper area of transformed curve .

please help!

Comment: Shouldn't $x$ be between $-1 \le x \le 2$? Because as it is, you have $2$ restraints for $y$, and none for $x$.

Comment: Your transformation is **not** a rotation. Besides, if it was, then the area of the new region would be equal to the area of $\Omega$.

Comment: why this is not rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Since the area of rectangle $\Omega$ can be gotten through

$$\int_\Omega 1 \ dz = \int_{-1}^2 \int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}1 \ dy \ dx = (2-(-1))\cdot\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\left(-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right) = 2\pi,$$

the transformed integral is simply:

$$\int_\Omega e^z \ dz = \int_{-1}^2 \int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} e^{x+iy} \ dy \ dx = \int_{-1}^2 \int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y)) \ dy \ dx = \\ = \int_{-1}^2 \left[e^x(\sin(y)-i\cos(y))\right]_{y=-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{y=\frac{\pi}{3}} \ dx = \int_{-1}^2 e^x\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{i}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) dx = \\ = \int_{-1}^2 \sqrt{3}\ e^x \  dx = \sqrt{3} \ \left[e^x\right]_{x=-1}^{x=2} = \sqrt{3}\ (e^2-e^{-1}).$$

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral_-1%5E2%28integral_%28-pi%2F3%29%5E%28pi%2F3%29%29%28e%5E%28x%2Biy%29%29dydx) also shows the integral (in a slightly different form, since $e^2-e^{-1} = \frac{e^3-1}{e}$).

**Edit:** Your transformation is not a simple rotation, it's a **combination** of a rotation and an enlargement centered at the origin. The resulting shape will be a skewed rectangle with curved sides, that is "wider", the farther we move away from the origin. See more examples of it  on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Complex_plane).